# Get all comments from a specific reddit thread in python

Tags: python, performance, praw, reddit

The official way,

```
r = praw.Reddit('Comment Scraper 1.0 by u/_Daimon_ see '
                 'https://praw.readthedocs.org/en/latest/'
                 'pages/comment_parsing.html')
submission = r.get_submission(submission_id='11v36o')
submission.replace_more_comments(limit=None, threshold=0)
```

is extremely slow. Is there a way to speed this up? There are people that have extracted every reddit comment into a database, so there must be some way to do this quicker.

Comment: Why the downvote? I couldn't find an answer elsewhere (if so please link me to it).

Comment: Protip: you can get any reddit page as JSON if you just append '.json' to the url. Then you loop inside a 'while True' clause as you page over the pages of the post and get the comments from the datastructure. No need for login or anything. Also I didn't downvote, but I can't help you reverse that because I spent all my votes :(

Comment: Nah that's not actually true, the JSON inclues these "more comments" things and it's very non-trivial to expand these properly (in the cases where there are more comments then you can see)

Comment: Notsoprotip then haha. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: what should we set as submission_id? did you just set a random item to it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Edit: the new praw api (6.0.0) has lists() which make the job easier:**

This also handles `AttributeError` that might occure due to `more_comments` through the use of `replace_more(limit=None)`

```
submissionList = []
submission.comments.replace_more(limit=None)
for comment in submission.comments.list():
    submissionList.append(comment)
```

**Edit: The new praw api (5.0.1) is magical and makes this much easier. Here is how to do it now:**

```
def getSubComments(comment, allComments, verbose=True):
  allComments.append(comment)
  if not hasattr(comment, "replies"):
    replies = comment.comments()
    if verbose: print("fetching (" + str(len(allComments)) + " comments fetched total)")
  else:
    replies = comment.replies
  for child in replies:
    getSubComments(child, allComments, verbose=verbose)


def getAll(r, submissionId, verbose=True):
  submission = r.submission(submissionId)
  comments = submission.comments
  commentsList = []
  for comment in comments:
    getSubComments(comment, commentsList, verbose=verbose)
  return commentsList
```

Example usage:

```
res = getAll(r, "6rjwo1")
#res = getAll(r, "6rjwo1", verbose=False) # This won't print out progress if you want it to be silent. Default is verbose=True
```

Where `r` is

```
username = 'myusernamehere'
userAgent = "MyAppName/0.1 by " + username
clientId = 'myClientId'
clientSecret = "myClientSecret"
password = "passwordformyusernamehere"
r = praw.Reddit(user_agent=userAgent, client_id=clientId, client_secret=clientSecret)
```

**Previous stuff (outdated now):**

Okay, I wrote code that can reliably pull every comment from a thread, and takes about 10 seconds for 500 comments, and about a minute for 4000 comments. I named this redApi.py Here it is:

```
import time
import requests
import requests.auth
import praw

username = 'myusernamehere'
userAgent = "MyAppName/0.1 by " + username
clientId = 'myClientId'
clientSecret = "myClientSecret"
password = "passwordformyusernamehere"

def getPraw():
  return praw.Reddit(user_agent=userAgent, client_id=clientId, client_secret=clientSecret)

global accessToken
accessToken = None

def getAccessToken():
  client_auth = requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth(clientId, clientSecret)
  post_data = {"grant_type": "password", "username": username, "password": password}
  headers = {"User-Agent": userAgent}
  response = requests.post("https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token", auth=client_auth, data=post_data, headers=headers)
  return response.json()

def makeRequest(apiUrl, useGet=True):
  global accessToken
  if accessToken is None:
    accessToken = getAccessToken()
  headers = {"Authorization": "bearer "  + accessToken['access_token'], "User-Agent": userAgent}
  if useGet:
    response = requests.get(apiUrl, headers=headers)
  else:
    response = requests.post(apiUrl, headers=headers)
  time.sleep(1.1)
  responseJson = response.json()
  if 'error' in responseJson:
    if responseJson['error'] == 401:
      print "Refreshing access token"
      time.sleep(1.1)
      accessToken = getAccessToken()
      headers = {"Authorization": "bearer "  + accessToken['access_token'], "User-Agent": userAgent}
      time.sleep(1.1)
      response = requests.get(apiUrl, headers=headers)
      responseJson = response.json()
  return responseJson


global prawReddit
prawReddit = praw.Reddit(user_agent=userAgent, client_id=clientId, client_secret=clientSecret)

# Gets any number of posts
def getPosts(subredditName, numPosts=1000):
  global prawReddit
  subreddit = prawReddit.get_subreddit(subredditName)

  postGetter = praw.helpers.submissions_between(prawReddit, subreddit)

  postArray = []
  numGotten = 0
  while numGotten < numPosts:
    postArray.append(postGetter.next())
    numGotten += 1

  return postArray






# Get all comments from a post
# Submission is a praw submission, obtained via:
# r = redApi.getPraw()
# submission = r.get_submission(submission_id='2zysz7') # (or some other submission id, found via https://www.reddit.com/r/test/comments/2zysz7/ayy/ - the thing after /comments/)
# comments = redApi.getComments(submission)
def getComments(submission):
  requestUrl = 'https://oauth.reddit.com/' + submission.subreddit.url + 'comments/article?&limit=1000&showmore=true&article=' + submission.id
  allData = makeRequest(requestUrl)
  articleData = allData[0]
  comments = allData[1]
  curComments = comments['data']['children']

  resultComments = getCommentsHelper(curComments, submission.name, submission)

  return resultComments




# Print out the tree of comments
def printTree(comments):
  return printTreeHelper(comments, "")


def printTreeHelper(comments, curIndentation):
  resultString = ""
  for comment in comments:
    resultString += curIndentation + comment['data']['body'].replace("\n", "\n" + curIndentation) + "\n"
    if not comment['data']['replies'] == "":
      resultString += printTreeHelper(comment['data']['replies']['data']['children'], curIndentation + "  ")
  return resultString

# Get all comments as a single array  
def flattenTree(comments):
  allComments = []
  for comment in comments:
    allComments.append(comment)
    if not comment['data']['replies'] == "":
      allComments += flattenTree(comment['data']['replies']['data']['children'])
  return allComments





# Utility functions for getComments
def expandCommentList(commentList, submission):

  curComments = commentList
  allComments = {}
  while True:
    thingsToExpand = []
    nextComments = []
    allParents = {}
    for comment in curComments:
      if comment['kind'] == "more":
        thingsToExpand += comment['data']['children']
      else:
        if comment['data']['body'][:len("If they are shipping")] == "If they are shipping":
          print comment
        allComments[comment['data']['name']] = comment

    if len(thingsToExpand) == 0:
      curComments = []
      break

    curComments = []
    if not len(thingsToExpand) == 0:
      print "total things to expand: " + str(len(thingsToExpand))
      for i in range(0, len(thingsToExpand)/100+1):
        curCommentIds = thingsToExpand[i*100:min((i+1)*100, len(thingsToExpand))]
        requestUrl = 'https://oauth.reddit.com/api/morechildren.json?api_type=json&link_id=' + submission.name + '&limit=1000&showmore=true&children=' + ",".join(curCommentIds)
        curData = makeRequest(requestUrl)
        if 'json' in curData and 'data' in curData['json']:
          curComments += curData['json']['data']['things']
        print (i+1)*100


  for comment in curComments:
    allComments[comment['data']['name']] = comment

  return allComments.values()


def lookForMore(comment):
  if comment['kind'] == "more":
    return True
  if not comment['data']['replies'] == "":
    for reply in comment['data']['replies']['data']['children']:
      if lookForMore(reply):
        return True
  return False

def getCommentsHelper(curComments, rootId, submission):

  allComments = expandCommentList(curComments, submission)

  commentMap = {}
  for comment in allComments:
    commentMap[comment['data']['name']] = comment


  allRootComments = []
  for comment in allComments:
    if comment['data']['parent_id'] == rootId:
      allRootComments.append(comment)
    elif comment['data']['parent_id'] in commentMap:
      parentComment = commentMap[comment['data']['parent_id']]
      if parentComment['data']['replies'] == "":
        parentComment['data']['replies'] = {'data': {'children': []}}
      alreadyChild = False
      for childComment in parentComment['data']['replies']['data']['children']:
        if childComment['data']['name'] == comment['data']['name']:
          alreadyChild = True
          break
      if not alreadyChild:
        parentComment['data']['replies']['data']['children'].append(comment)
    else:
      print "pls halp"

  completedComments = []
  needMoreComments = []

  for comment in allRootComments:
    if not comment['data']['replies'] == "" or comment['kind'] == 'more':
      hasMore = lookForMore(comment)

      if hasMore:
        needMoreComments.append(comment)
      else:
        replyComments = getCommentsHelper(comment['data']['replies']['data']['children'], comment['data']['name'], submission)
        comment['data']['replies']['data']['children'] = replyComments
        completedComments.append(comment)
    else:
      completedComments.append(comment)
  for comment in needMoreComments:
    requestUrl = 'https://oauth.reddit.com/' + submission.subreddit.url + 'comments/article?&limit=1000&showmore=true&article=' + submission.id + "&comment=" + comment['data']['id']
    allData = makeRequest(requestUrl)
    articleData = allData[0]
    comment = allData[1]['data']['children'][0]
    if comment['data']['replies'] == "":
      completedComments.append(comment)
    else:
      comments = comment['data']['replies']['data']['children']
      actualComments = getCommentsHelper(comments, comment['data']['name'], submission)
      comment['data']['replies']['data']['children'] = actualComments
      completedComments.append(comment)

  return completedComments
```

To use this script, in a python prompt, type the following:

```
# Get all comments from a post
# Submission is a praw submission, obtained via:
r = redApi.getPraw()
submission = r.get_submission(submission_id='2zysz7') # (or some other submission id, found via https://www.reddit.com/r/test/comments/2zysz7/ayy/ - the thing after /comments/)
comments = redApi.getComments(submission)
```

Comment: To use this, you need to install PRAW from [here](https://github.com/praw-dev/praw). You need to download the zip and do python setup.py install, because the pip and easy_install versions are different and don't have the same functionality. This could probably also be done in those, but all of the documentation they have is for this version.

Comment: Also, sadly, this only seems to work for posts with 5000 or so comments or less. The bigger ones it struggles with and throws an error. I'm working on this right now.

Comment: when I am running your code I get `KeyError: 'access_token'` error. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Very helpful! Thanks!

Comment: Looks like your praw 5.0.1 was giving the correct comment tree using dfs. The latest version (the one using list) only gives the top level comments first, then gives the next level comments, and so on.

Comment: like a boss ;) much appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

Looks like praw has been updated? In 4.5.1 it looks more like:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
import praw

reddit = praw.Reddit(
    client_id='<client_id>',
    client_secret='<client_secret>',
    user_agent='davehodg/0.1')

submission = reddit.submission(id='<submission_id>')
sumbission = reddit.submission(url='<submission_url>') #in case you don't have submission id

for comment in submission.comments.list():
    print(comment.body)
```

Edit: seems like the most I can get back is 1000 comments?

Answer (score 1):

Im adding a bunch of prints and debugging, but right now @danielle your script does nothing.  Just returned back to prompt.

Comment: I added a description of how to use it as well. You had to call a function in the script, sorry if that was unclear.

Comment: Also, at the top of the script you need to fill in your relevant reddit API developer details.